# How does this FileWriter Work?

Tags: java, filereader

Heres a code :

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileCharCopier
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
  {

    File f1=new File("scjp.txt");
    File f2=new File("scjpcopy.txt");

    FileReader in=new FileReader(f1);
    FileWriter out=new FileWriter(f2);

    int c;

    while((c=in.read())!=1)
            {
      out.write(c);
      in.close();
      out.flush();
      out.close();


  }
}
}
```

I have both scjp and scjpcopy.txt in the same directory

but when I run the program, I get these errors :

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at FileCharCopier.main(FileCharCopier.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

line 18 refers to

```
out.write(c);
```

can somebody correct the error ?

Comment: You've close both the input and output streams within the first loop, so on the second loop round, it's causing the exception

Comment: In addition to the elementary error pointed out in comments an answers, you certainly shouldn't be copying a char at a time. You should use a char array: 'while ((count = in.read(array)) > 0) out.write(array, 0, count);' It is many times as fast. Or else a BufferedReader and a BufferedWriter.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you are closing both the input and output steams on the first iteration of the `while-loop`.  This means that when you try and loop through the second time, the streams are closed and it's throwing the exception.

Instead, you should close the streams when you are done with them, for example.

```
public class FileCharCopier {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        File f1 = new File("scjp.txt");
        File f2 = new File("scjpcopy.txt");

        FileReader in = null;
        FileWriter out = null;

        try {

            in = new FileReader(f1);
            out = new FileWriter(f2);

            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != 1) {
                out.write(c);
            }

            out.flush();

        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This uses a `try-finally` block to ensure that all best efforts are made to close the streams either when the loop exists or some error occurs.

Now, if you're lucky enough to be using Java 7, you can use the `try-with-resources` statement instead, for example...

```
public class FileCharCopier {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        File f1 = new File("scjp.txt");
        File f2 = new File("scjpcopy.txt");

        try (FileReader in = new FileReader(f1); FileWriter out = new FileWriter(f2)) {

            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != 1) {
                out.write(c);
            }

            out.flush();

        } finally {
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at [The `try-with-resources` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `in.close()` and `out.close()` from while loop and make it like this :

```
while((c=in.read())!=1)
{
  out.write(c);
  out.flush();
}
```

What it does : After reading one character from file, it closes the reader so `in` was no more attached with input file and throws exception.

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#close%28%29) Oracle's Doc. It is written that :
`Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it. Once the stream has been closed, further read(), ready(), mark(), reset(), or skip() invocations will throw an IOException. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.`

Answer (score 0):

Put your `out.close();` and `in.close()` outside the while loop.

Its closing the outputstream each time. After writting all the stuff, you can close it outside the while loop.

Hope thats helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the stream while you are still trying to write to them.Move the clean up process out of the loop.

```
import java.io.*;
public class FileCharCopier
{
  //...same
    while((c=in.read())!=1){
          out.write(c);
          out.flush();
    }
          in.close();              
          out.close();
    }
}
```